# Full Calendar 5.6.0 and Bootstrap 5

Tags: fullcalendar, bootstrap-5, fullcalendar-5

we are using Full Calendar on a webtie that uses Bootstrap in the Version 5 Beta.

I realized that the bootstrap theme for FullCalendar is made for Bootstrap 4, and is not fully compatible with Bootstrap 5.

Example of the implementation is here:
https://dev.swingstep.net/classes/heidelberg/heidelberg-calendar/

Eg:

- Table borders are not recognized (maybe because there is a table inside a table?)
- The modal "close" button is not working, though that also happens when I switch to standard theme, so maybe not bootstrap related.

Has anyone else encounterered this incompatibility - what would be the best way to go about it?
Is there a Bootstrap 5-ready version of the plugin on its way?

Best wishes, Oli

Comment: Modal button would be unrelated to the visual theme as you correctly state. If you want to know what fullCalendar is working on, ask them at their GitHub site. AFAIK no-one involved in the project looks at stackoverflow regularly. The folks here just try to help with people's implementation issues.

Comment: The "best" way to deal with the issue is a bit subjective but arguably if there are multiple problems then it might be wise to create your own bespoke theme which fixes them all. You could try and contribute it to the fullcalendar project if they are interested.

Comment: About the close button in modal: you are using `data-dismiss="modal"`. In BS 5 it must be: `data-bs-dismiss="modal"`

Comment: @JackMaessen yes true about th emodal I realized that afterwards, this has nothing to do with the calendar theme and I fixed it. About the theme-related stuff I also wrote their support, so I see what they get back, but right now I just switched to the default theme which works fine enough for now :) 

thanks for all your responses :)